# How can I use ECDSA in C# with a key size of less than the built in minimum of 256-bits

Tags: c#, cryptography, hash, signing, cng

I have a very limited channel within which to send messages and signatures, and have been indicated (over at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3075/asymmetric-algorithm-to-generate-compact-unique-messages-that-can-be-validated/) that ECDSA offers the most compact asymmetrical algorithm going.

I've got this going fairly easily as:

```
void Main()
{
    byte[] publickey;
    byte[] data;
    byte[] signature;

    using (var dsa = new ECDsaCng(256))
    {
        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        publickey = dsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);

        data = new byte[] { 21, 5, 8, 12, 207 };

        signature = dsa.SignData(data);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(signature.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(signature));

    using (var dsa = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(publickey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)))
    {
        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

        if (dsa.VerifyData(data, signature))
            Console.WriteLine("Data is good");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Data is bad");
    }
}
```

But I'd like to be able to sacrifice some strength and use less than the minimum 256-bit key size that the BCL offers, and I haven't found an implementation that will do what I need.

I've tried BouncyCastle and that seems to out of the box have the same limitation.

What are my options? Is there another implementation out there that lifts the implementation limitation?

Comment: I removed my answer; as you rightly point out, too much of the implementation is internal to System.Security.

Comment: Yeah afraid so - I've tried setting the internal field values for the KeySizeValue and that just causes further problems. Internally it tries to select a key generation algorithm that just doesnt exist.

Comment: Did you try the lightweight API of Bouncy Castle? I don't know the C# variant (as I am a Java programmer) but I know for certain that the lightweight  API in Java has no restrictions regarding key size (it even has plenty "named curves" stored with key sizes < 256).

Comment: @owlstead yes I gave it a go (in the C# port) but couldn't find an obvious way to do it as its a bit opaque and the documentation was down. Have you got a link to the appropriate place?

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/download/bccrypto-net-1.7-src.zip includes tests (can be used as samples) and documentation. I'll inform the BC maintainers about the wiki.

Comment: Wiki should be fixed now - thanks to David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the lightweight Bouncy Castle library to perform EC cryptography with almost any curve over F(2m) or F(P), including those with smaller bitsizes. I would recommend you to use standard curves such as the ones defined in the `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Nist.NistNamedCurves` class.

The smallest NIST curve is 163 bit although I would recommend going for 192 bit minimum for non-real time communications. Note that that would only save you about 16 bytes in total compared to a 256 bit named curve (256 - 192 = 64 bits, 64 * 2 / 8 = 16 bytes).

Brainpool curves are also well rather safely generated and well defined. You can find them in the `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.TeleTrusT` namespace.